# Sentry SDK - How to make raven test call with new client?

Tags: django, sentry

In the now deprecated package `raven` there was a django management command to test the setup: `manage.py raven test`.

The new [SentrySDK](https://pypi.org/project/sentry-sdk/) does not [show how to do it in the django docs](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/django/) nor does it have any management commands.

Any ideas about that topic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to untitaker at [GitHub](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python/issues/367) we have a solution:

```
from sentry_sdk import capture_message
capture_message("hi")
```

You can open the django shell and execute the command:

```
python manage.py shell
```